# Bootstrap 3 + IE11 + HTML5 not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, respond.js

I have a problem with getting my page to display properly in ie11, in chrome it works perfectly but when I switch to IE11 it does not.

In Chrome it is a responsive masonry grid and in IE it uses full width and stacks every article on top.

I have tried html5shiv, respond.js modernizr, I tried wp_enqeueing it, tried including the scripts in the footer, header and also linked them through a cdn but also stored locally.

What do I need to do?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Freek Bellinga</title>
        <!-- Awesome Font -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <!-- Google fonts -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic|Old+Standard+TT:400,700,400italic|Cookie' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Style CSS  -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>



<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand website-title" href="#">Mijn Limericks</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-default">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Over Mij</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categoriëen</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>






        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

               <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center bg">
      <img src="img/stoel.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      <h1>Stoel</h1>
      <span>16 maart, 2015</span>
      <p class="limerick-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center bg">
       <img src="img/langejaap.jpg" class="img-responsive">
       <h1>Lange Jaap</h1>
      <span>16 maart, 2015</span>
      <p class="limerick-text">een boegbeeld van ver waargenomen
        de Lange Jaap bij de stad mijner dromen
        het gevoel van geluk
        mijn dag kan niet meer stuk
        in de polder is het dubbel thuiskomen</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center bg">
       <img src="img/zeester.jpg" class="img-responsive">
       <h1>Zee ster</h1>
      <span>16 maart, 2015</span>
      <p class="limerick-text">een zeester verrast en verlegen
        heeft onverwacht bezoek gekregen
        zij bad stil en blij
        blijf voor altijd bij mij
        en durft zich haast niet te bewegen</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center bg">
       <img src="img/zeegolf.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <h1>Golf</h1>
      <span>16 maart, 2015</span>
      <p class="limerick-text"> een foto na uren verkregen
machtige golf ,windkracht negen
mijn dorp aan de zee
sluit haar ogen in bée
tsunami wendt tijdig haar steven</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center bg">
       <img src="//placehold.it/430" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center bg">
       <img src="//placehold.it/400" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center bg">
       <img src="//placehold.it/490" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center bg">
       <img src="//placehold.it/480" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center bg">
      <img src="//placehold.it/530" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center bg">
       <img src="//placehold.it/460" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center bg">
       <img src="//placehold.it/430" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center bg">
       <img src="//placehold.it/400" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
</div>




        <div class="container">
    <hr>
        <div class="text-center center-block">
            <p class="txt-railway">- Einde -</p>
            <br />
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bootsnipp"><i id="social" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i></a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/bootsnipp"><i id="social" class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i></a>
                <a href="https://plus.google.com/+Bootsnipp-page"><i id="social" class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-3x"></i></a>
                <a href="mailto:bootsnipp@gmail.com"><i id="social" class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-3x"></i></a>
</div>
    <hr>
</div>


        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the css I am using:

```
body {
    background-color: #E1E3E4;
}

/* Setting default typography */
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .03em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 27px;
    color:#4d4d4d;
}

h3 {
    color: #bebebe;
    font-size: 16,8px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding-top:1%;
    letter-spacing: .06em;
}

a.website-title {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline;
}

.article-date{
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #00a0e9;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1 > a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

h1 > a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#404237;
}

h1 > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
     color:#404237;
     background-color: #00a0e9;
     color: #fff;
}

h1 > a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* End of default typography */

/* Setting up div classes */

.row.index-row {
 -moz-column-width: 20em;
 -webkit-column-width: 20em;
 -moz-column-gap: 10px;
 -webkit-column-gap:10px; 
}

.row > .col-lg-3 {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 10px;
 width:  96%; 
 float:none;
}

.limerick {
    background-color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.article-content {
    padding: 1em .8571428571em .2857142857em;
}

.img-responsive {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Styling for single.php */
/* Typography single.php if needed */
h1 {

}

h2 {

}

h3 {

}

p {

}

/* End of typography styling */

/* Author post */


/* Styling div elements for single.php */

.row.single-php-row {
 -moz-column-width: 100%;
 -webkit-column-width: 100%;
 -moz-column-gap: 10px;
 -webkit-column-gap:10px; 
}

.limerick.single-php-img {
    width:50%;
}





/* End of styling div elements for single.php */
```

Comment: What do you mean by "display properly"? What specific issues are you seeing?

Comment: Sorry kind of dumb not to include that, well On chrome it is like a masonry grid, in IE it just uses full width for every article.

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues in my IE11. Can you recreate this in a fiddle?

Comment: Hi, you can see a live example on www.mijnlimericks.nl/wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at your live site, I found the issue. It was in an additional CSS file you have.

In your `.index-row`s, you are using the prefixed versions of `column-width` and `column-gap` for Firefox/Chrome. IE needs the non-prefixed versions.

```
.row.index-row {
 -moz-column-width: 20em;
 -webkit-column-width: 20em;
 column-width: 20em;
 -moz-column-gap: 10px;
 -webkit-column-gap:10px; 
 column-gap:10px; 
}
```

Please add this missing CSS to the question so any future users can see the whole problem/solution.